# Groovy Json parsing

Tags: java, json, parsing, groovy

Hi i am bit new and need help to parse a hash, for example data:
in current example,i want to loop through all keys `TEST-A,TEST-B,TEST-C` and change their value (app-id), for now  using jsonslurper i can parse and edit value per key like this:

```
parsed.'TEST-A'[0].app_id = a
```

but what i want is to read keys and assign values (these value i will be reading as String)

---

```
import groovy.json.*
data = '''
{
    "TEST-A":   [{ "app_id":"aaa" }],
    "TEST-B":   [{ "app_id":"bbb" }],
    "TEST-C":   [{ "app_id":"ccc" }]
}'''

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)
String a= 'test';
parsed.'TEST-A'[0].app_id = a
def result = JsonOutput.toJson(parsed)
println "result: $result"
```

Comment: Result of current example: result: {"TEST-A":[{"app_id":"test"}],"TEST-B":[{"app_id":"bbb"}],"TEST-C":[{"app_id":"ccc"}]}

Comment: it's not clear what do you want

Comment: What i want is loop through all keys like TEST-A,TEST-B, ... check and edit the key values if it is for that key, like in the example i am doing only for TEST-A,

Comment: so what is the problem to do it for 2 other keys like you are doing for TEST_A?

Comment: I want to check the key for which i have to edit the value, not for all the Keys, in later step i like to develop the code in such a way, as i will be reading the keys and only edit the value of a key i am reading ,,  so i am not sure if i can do something like " parsed.each do |keys|"? to loop through and add a check if "fif value need to be edited for that key"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import groovy.json.*
data = '''
{
    "TEST-A":   [{ "app_id":"aaa" }],
    "TEST-B":   [{ "app_id":"bbb" }],
    "TEST-C":   [{ "app_id":"ccc" }]
}'''

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)
def a = 665
parsed.each{k,v-> 
  if(k in ['TEST-A','TEST-B','TEST-C']) v[0].app_id = a
}

println new JsonBuilder(parsed).toPrettyString()
```

output:

```
{
    "TEST-A": [
        {
            "app_id": 665
        }
    ],
    "TEST-B": [
        {
            "app_id": 665
        }
    ],
    "TEST-C": [
        {
            "app_id": 665
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: lets say is k=Test_A,  this should edit the value of k, right? but it is throughing an error

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing your "json" object through can look like:

```
import groovy.json.*
data = '''
{
    "TEST-A":   [{ "app_id":"aaa" }],
    "TEST-B":   [{ "app_id":"bbb" }],
    "TEST-C":   [{ "app_id":"ccc" }]
}'''

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)
String a= 'test';

parsed.each{ it.value[0].app_id = a } // < here is MAGIC!

def result = JsonOutput.toJson(parsed)
println "result:\n${JsonOutput.prettyPrint(result)}"
```

gives

```
result:
{
    "TEST-A": [
        {
            "app_id": "test"
        }
    ],
    "TEST-B": [
        {
            "app_id": "test"
        }
    ],
    "TEST-C": [
        {
            "app_id": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I want to check the key for which i have to edit the value, not for all the Keys, in later step i like to develop the code in such a way, as i will be reading the keys and only edit the value of a key i am reading